# Rebuild precompiled header

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oracle-pro-c

I am trying to use MFC with ProC.
Functions.pc is where I do the ProC syntax to connect to the database. So I include the `'Functions.h'` in the dialog model where I want to call the functions in `'Funtions.h'`. And now I got this error.

```
    Add directive to 'stdafx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
```

I understand that I need to include `'stdafx.h'` to `'Functions.h'` for it to work. And I did that. It can compile,but then when I try to run the program,it won't recognize the syntax of ProC created by the `'Functions.cpp'` created. I don't really understand how to rebuild the precompiled header since I don't understand the codes in `'stdafx.h'`.

Comment: From which part are you saying?

Comment: @tokwan: It's in the tag wiki. If you mouse-over a tag, it shows the wiki for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix .pch file missing on build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096384/how-to-fix-pch-file-missing-on-build)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution myself. I need to set the properties of that .cpp file to not using any pre-compiled header.

Comment: @Nick It's been a while, can't really remember. But you can just right click on the cpp file and change the setting accordingly. I'm using Visual Studio for this. Click the link for the screenshot http://goo.gl/cKA8mZ

Comment: @Nick How to disable precompiled headers for a CPP file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9319031/1879699

Answer (score 14):

The common way to use precompiled headers on windows is

1. Include system , third party headers or infrequently changing headers in **stdadx.h**
2. **stdafx.cpp** usually only includes **stdafx.h**
3. All your project cpp files include **stdafx.h** as the first header
4. Your project header files **should not include stdafx.h**

To trigger a precompiled header rebuild,

1. Modify **stdafx.h** and do an incremental build
2. Or Do a rebuild project

Answer (score 3):

Within VS 2012 you can set the properties of the Project, the Solution, or Source File(s) to not use Precompiled Headers. See attached graphic for how to do it...
[VS Turn off Precompiled Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xrbx.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

In VS2017, this error persisted until I switched Project Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Precompiled Headers > Precompiled Header setting from "Use (/Yu)" to "Create (/Yc)".

For the **project** setting, use:

- "Create" for pre-compiled headers to be produced by the project
- "Use" for pre-compiled headers produced by **another** project

For **per-file** settings, use:

- "Create" for the stdafx.cpp file **only**
- "Use" for all other `.c` and `.cpp` files