# Can't disable precompiled headers for single C file in VS2015

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, precompiled-headers

I'm trying to disable precompiled headers for the C files of my project because VS2015 gives me this error (line broken for readability):

```
..\..\..\..\Lib\freetype2\src\autofit\autofit.c : fatal error C1853: 
  'Y:\obj\TwoNav_PC_15\headers\CompeTwoNav.pch' precompiled header file 
  is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header 
  is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)
```

Looking on how to do it I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318951/disabling-precompiled-headers-for-a-specific-file-in-a-vc-2010-project),
but when I try to do it in my Visual Studio 2015 Professional, I can't see the option referred to.

**Edit**: This is how I try to select the properties:

[image]

This image is what I see when I select the properties of the file:

[image: File Properties dialogbox]

Comment: Remove all .pch files the compiler complains about.

Comment: You only selected the file, you are looking at the wrong tool window.  Instead, right-click it and choose Properties to bring up the property pages for the file.

Comment: @n.m. Deleted even the entire folder.. no luck.

Comment: @HansPassant I edited the post with an image showing what I click when trying to select properties.

Comment: You are still looking at the wrong tool window.  I don't know why you can't see the settings dialog for the file, maybe your VS2015 install is broken.  Try another machine.

Comment: @HansPassant I found a workaround, its explained in the answer. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround to make the right tool I needed appear... I leave it here as an answer in case someone else encounters this problem.

It won't appear by clicking file -> *Properties*, but it appears when clicking project -> *Properties* so, once opened, I selected the file autofit.c from the tree view and finally I could disable precompiled headers from this  single file !

[image]

Comment: Wow,Of course you can @shrike didn't you see the question linked? Moreover, if you take a look at my screenshot, I am in the property page of the file **autofit.c** not in the project properties. So, yes, I can **Not Use** precompiled headers for a single file and **Use** them for the rest of the project.

Comment: You're right, indeed.(Should better refrain commenting sometimes...) Now I know it is possible, comment removed so far, thanks.