# fatal error C1083: Cannot open precompiled header file

Tags: xml, visual-c++, console-application

I have created a win32 console project by the name of xml read. I have included and used many dll and headers

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#using <msxml3.dll>
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <System.xml.dll>
using namespace MSXML2; 
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Xml;
```

I have included external folders and references to include these dll.

However, When compiling, following error is thrown

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open precompiled header file: 'Debug\xmlread.pch': No such file or directory

I have not included this header in my code; what does this error indicate

Comment: Your project settings are not correct.  Always use the provided project template when you start a new project to fall in the pit of success.  File > New > Project > Visual C++ > CLR > CLR Console Application.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I still don't understand though what exactly is .pch for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix .pch file missing on build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096384/how-to-fix-pch-file-missing-on-build)