# Compile Error: Cannot open precompiled header.pch -- No such file or directory

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

I have recently purchased the text "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup and have been following it through. I am currently stuck on an early project, where I need to output some strings of text. Using Visual Studio Community 2015 update 1, on a Windows 10 Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro laptop, I have attempted to compile the project but have ran into an error detailed:

"Cannot open precompiled header file: Debug\Finding the Upstairs Bathroom.pch': No such file or directory". The name of the project is aptly named "Finding the Upstairs Bathroom.cpp". Here is the code:

```
// I have the headers "stdafx.h" as well as this specific header lib 
// Bjarne Stroustrup created and which I had linked
// called "../../std_lib_facilities.h", which contains the standard C++ lib functions.

(#) define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS 1

int main()`// Main function`

{  
    cout << "Take the key out of your right pants pocket\n"; // Outputs string of text

    cout << "Unlock the front door of the house\n";

    cout << "Open the front door and step inside\n";

    cout << "Lock the front door using the key\n";

    cout << "Move up the stairs, taking them two at a time\n";

    cout << "Walk to the second door on the left and face it directly\n";

    cout << "Using the door handle, turn it and push the door forward\n";

    cout << "Enter the bathroom while leaving the door open behind you\n";

    keep_window_open();

    return 0;
}
```

I would be grateful if someone is able to figure out how to fix my error.

Comment: show all of your includes

Comment: I would turn off pre compiled headers, or learn how to use them. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4w02hte.aspx

Comment: My includes are:

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<stdexcept>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix .pch file missing on build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096384/how-to-fix-pch-file-missing-on-build)

Comment: Also, you seem to be using MFC (haven't used VS for a while, but I'm pretty sure that's the case). If you'd like to learn C++, better avoid such frameworks, and make do with the standard library.

Comment: I'm not using MFC. I'm solely using the C++ standard library

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 options to solve this:

- Rebuild the full project. This should (re)create the precompiled header (or select `Build/Clean Solution` first).
- Turn off precompiled headers. `Project settings / C/C++ / Precompiled headers / Not Using Precompiled Headers`.

Comment: I decided to create a completely new project and do the exact same thing, but this time I did not precompile headers. It successfully compiled. Thankyou for the help.

Comment: @Rudis - Ok, but `Build -> Clean Solution` should also work on your other project (and then a full rebuild).

Comment: I will keep that in mind if I have an error similar to this one day

Comment: plus 1 for clean solution - note: I already create pch.h yc and have this problem regardless that's where clean comes in

Answer (score 12):

Make sure StdAfx.cpp>right-click>Properties (not the same as +enter) has `'Precompiled Header'='Create /Yc'`

The rest of the .cpp files should have `'Precompiled Header'='Use /Yu'`

Comment: After hours of grief on a large geacy project the above solved my problem.

Comment: This should be the selected answer. The current selected answer only avoids the issue. This solves it and explains the difference between create and use.

Answer (score 4):

Appart from the options presented by Danny_ds, you can:

- Create precompiled headers: `Project settings / C/C++ / Precompiled Headers`

  `Precompiled Headers: Create (/Yc)`

  [image: Create VS precompiled headers]
- Disable precompiled headers. `Project settings / C/C++ / Precompiled Headers`

  `Precompiled Headers: Not Using Precompiled Headers`

I had the problem when I first had to **create** the precompiled header.

Comment: My problem was project defaulted to Use instead of Create.