# OpenCV matrix creation

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.1 in Visual Studio 2008. I've been trying to create a matrix and I've tried the commands `cvCreateMat()`, `Mat.M`, and `M.create` etc... But none of these commands got compiled. There is always some error, e.g when I use this command:

```
M(2,2,CV_8UC3,Scalar(0,0,255));
```

I get the following error:

```
'Mat' : undeclared identifier
```

the other time I used this command:

```
CvMat* mat = cvCreateMat( 5, 5,8UC1);
```

And the  error was:

```
syntax error : 'bad suffix on number'
```

Could anyone let me know what's the issue...

Comment: I think c++ interface is not implemented in opencv2.1

Comment: So you're saying that I have to move to another version of openCV???@houssem Bdr

Comment: yes, i think it will be the occasion. It is easy anyway and better to work with c++ interface. Move to 2.4.4

Comment: but there is one thing,I saw opencv 2.1 tutorial and mat commands were shown...which means that c++ commands can be implemented in opencv 2.1???@houssem Badr

Comment: C++ interface **is** available in 2.1. Please check your headers - best start with a tutorial on how to write your first OpenCV app - most probably you did not configure your project correctly

Comment: It's working fine for other data types namely IPl* image.....I've compiled programs and they wrork fine,the issue lies with matrices...@sammy

Answer (score 3):

In C++  use `cv::Mat`

`cv::Mat A;`

`A.create(3,3,CV_8UC1);`

or

`using namespace cv;`

`Mat B(3,3,CV_8UC1);`

Use `cvMat` if you are in C.

Comment: I tried this but I get this error:Cannot open precompiled header file: 'Debug\OpenCV_basics.pch': No such file or directory@Barshan Das

Comment: @AaymanKhalid see this : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574121/precompiled-headers-with-dll-solutions-cannot-open-precompiled-header-file